# Sublime Text through command line: Don't open more than 1 window/instance, add to working project instead

Tags: sublimetext

It's pretty unclear the philosophy of Sublime Text (3 in my case) concerning opening program from command line.

With version 2, if I wanted to open Sublime with the current working directory I would type `subl . &`.
With version 3, the `&` has become optional, the instance is automatically sent to the background.

That's good, but if there already was an instance of sublime to be restored, both window become open.

[image: Multiple Sublime Windows]

What I'd expect by running `subl .`

- If an instance is already stored, it opens and adds `.` (working directory) to the left panel (they call it Add to the project)
- Else do the current behavior

Is there any chance I can achieve that?

Maybe I should use what they call `project`, but that's pretty unnatural to me: sublime should open and close files, so only 1 window, with many folders in the left panel I can manage is the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cool, I found it:

`subl --add .`

From `subl --help`.

I've aliased it: `alias subl="subl --add"`